# Creating the Hash from this array

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this

```
[["DataSetId", "DataSet-1", "DataSet-1"], ["Did", "DataSet-1", "DataSet-2"], ["Company Name", "Company1", "Company2"]]
```

I want an array of Hashes as given below

```
[{"DataSetId"=>"DataSet-1","Did"=>"DataSet-1","Company Name"=>"Company1"},{"DataSetId"=>"DataSet-1","Did"=>"DataSet-2","Company Name"=>"Company2"}]
```

The first element should be the key and the rest of the elements in the array are the values. Values may increase for an example here, key is `"Did"` and the values are `"DataSet-1", "DataSet-2"`.

The array which has three elements here are dynamic which would include more elements like ["Did", "DataSet-1", "DataSet-2","DataSet-3","DataSet-4"] and that would be decided in the run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash.
  map { |a| [a.first].product(a[1..-1]) }.
  reduce(&:zip).
  map { |a| a.flatten.each_slice(2).each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v } }
#⇒ [{"DataSetId"=>"DataSet-1", "Did"=>"DataSet-1", "Company Name"=>"Company1"},
#   {"DataSetId"=>"DataSet-1", "Did"=>"DataSet-2", "Company Name"=>"Company2"}]
```

I am pretty sure the last transform might be done in a more elegant manner, but I cannot figure out how.

**UPD** Figured out:

```
hash.
  map { |a| [a.first].product(a[1..-1]) }.
  reduce(&:zip).
  map { |a| Hash[*a.flatten] }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I figured out the proper way for the last transform.

Comment: yep, that works properly too. Upvoted!